# hover effect with text to a menu item

Tags: css

I want to apply a (hover) effect to a menu item on the main menu of a website.
If you click on the menu item "HOW" for example, a subpage will follow.
As an extra effect, I want to see an extra (sub) text under the text HOE (only after mouse-over).
Example: if you hover your mouse over the menu item with the name "HOW", I want an extra text to appear under the word "HOW".
I have already tested two extensions for this, unfortunately without visible results.
This is the website:
https://www.groenekoers.nl/Joost/

Regards, Ronald

Comment: Off topic, but I love that transitions when you scroll. Good job!

Comment: Thanx for the feedback, Sen!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="page" class="element">
  HOW
</div>

<style>
    .element:hover:after {
        display: inline;
        content: 'HOE';
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Danon, thanx for your help! Could you do the coding for me (paid)?

Comment: @DJDUCKO Yea,  I think I could

Comment: Thanx, I will come back to you!

Comment: Danon, could you send me a message, about how you can fix this for me?

Comment: how can I contact you? Could you send me a message, about how you can fix this for me? – DJ DUCKO

Comment: @DJDUCKO h4t3r2.g0nn4.ha73@gmail.com contact me